# Is it tent of meeting or tabernacle in Leviticus 10:7?

Tags: leviticus

New International Version

> Do not leave the entrance to the **tent of meeting** [אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֔ד Ohel Moed] or you will die, because the LORD's anointing oil is on you." So they did as Moses said.

New Living Translation

> But you must not leave the entrance of the **Tabernacle** or you will die, for you have been anointed with the LORD’s anointing oil.” So they did as Moses commanded.

The original Hebrew אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֔ד (Ohel Moed) says tent of meeting. 19 versions from https://biblehub.com/leviticus/10-7.htm translate it as tent of meeting. Still 9 versions translate it as tabernacle. Why?

Comment: It might be better to use the following for your reference:       וַתֵּ֕כֶל כָּל־עֲבֹדַ֕ת מִשְׁכַּ֖ן אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֑ד
, (Ex 39:32, BHS).  Ex 39:32; 40:2, 6, 29, cf. 1 Ch 6:17 (BDB)  all have the same structure and BDB references these verses as distinguishing  מִשְׁכַּ֖ן and אֹ֣הֶל מוֹעֵ֑ד.

Comment: I'll add that as a separate question.

Comment: They are the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it tent of meeting or tabernacle in Leviticus 10:7?

**The Tabernacle,**

Was a transportable tent used by the Israelites after they left Egypt. The tent was used for worship and sacrifice by the Israelites and it housed the ark of the covenant. It was also sometimes referred to as a **" tent of meeting"**.  It was a framework of wooden panels and was divided into two rooms, the first room was called Holy and the second Most Holy.

Joshua 18:1  (NASB)

Rest of the Land Divided

> 18 Then the whole congregation of the sons of Israel assembled
> themselves at Shiloh, and set up the **tent of meeting** there; and
> the land was subdued before them.

Exodus 25:9  (NASB)

> 9 According to all that I am going to show you, as the pattern of the
> **tabernacle** and the pattern of all its furniture, just so you shall construct

Answer (score 1):

"Tabernacle" is the old "English" word for a "tent".  The phrase in Lev 10:7 is מוֹעֵ֜ד אֹ֨הֶל which is definitely "tent of meeting".

As explained in another question [Tent of meeting vs tabernacle](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/50620/tent-of-meeting-vs-tabernacle) , the "tent of meeting" is also called the "tabernacle", or simply "tent", Ex 39:32, 40:2, 6, 22, 24, 35, Lev 17:4, Num 3:7, 8, 4:25, 31, etc.

Thus, a literal translation of Lev 10:7 would read, "tent of meeting" ("tabernacle of meeting" would be just as accurate).  However, the translation, "tabernacle" for "tent of meeting" is an interpretive translation.

The ancient Israelite sacred Tabernacle was also know by other names apart of the "tent of meeting" such as:

- "tent of covenant law", Num 9:15, 1:50, 53, Ex 38:21, etc.