# Moses stayed in the tent outside the camp for how long

Tags: moses, tabernacle

Moses pitched the tent outside the camp after the golden calf incident.  How long before returning to the mountain with the new tablets?

> Ex 33:7 - Now Moses used to take the tent and pitch it at a distance
> outside the camp. He called it the Tent of Meeting, and anyone
> inquiring of the LORD would go to the Tent of Meeting outside the
> camp.

Comment: Welcome to BH. Do read the tour [below, left] to see how this site works. Please edit into your question the Bible verse that leads you to this question. Then we can all know where you are working from.

Answer (score 0):

According to Exodus 33:7, Moses used to take the tent and pitch it outside the camp, calling it the "Tent of Meeting." It is not specified how long he stayed in the tent before returning to the mountain with the new tablets.

References:
Here's an inline link to the [Bible Hub](https://biblehub.com/exodus/33-7.htm) for Exodus 33:7.
Here's a reference-style link to [Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/50620/tent-of-meeting-vs-tabernacle) discussing the "Tent of Meeting" versus Tabernacle.
Here's a very readable link to a commentary on [The Bible Says](https://thebiblesays.com/commentary/exod/exod-33/exodus-337-11/) regarding Exodus 33:7-11.
Check the NIV version on [Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus+33%3A7-11&version=NIV) for Exodus 33:7-11.
Explore the ESV version on [Biblia](https://biblia.com/bible/esv/exodus/33/7-11) for Exodus 33:7-11.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question because there were two tents with the title, "Tent of Meeting" as follows:

1. The tabernacle of God containing the Ark of the Covenant, the Menorah and Shew-bread, was called the "tent of meeting" because it also contained the Shechinah glory.  Ex 27:21, 29:4, 10, 42, 44, 30:16, 18, 36, 31:7, 35:21, etc. This tent was placed **at the center of the Israelite camp**. Num 2:1, 2.
2. The tent Moses used for settling disputes where Moses met with God.  Ex 33:7, 10. This tent was pitched **outside the Israelite camp** and was used as a temporary substitute for the main tabernacle until the latter was built (as per ex 40).

**Timing**

We are not told anything about how long the process lasted between Moses smashing the original stone tablet and their replacement.  So we do not know.

However, what we are told is this:

> Num 10:11-13 - On the twentieth day of the second month of the second
> year, the cloud was lifted from above the tabernacle of the Testimony,
> 12and the Israelites set out from the Wilderness of Sinai, traveling
> from place to place until the cloud settled in the Wilderness of
> Paran. 13They set out this first time according to the LORD’s command
> through Moses.

Thus, the Israelites had been camped at the foot of Sinai for almost a year during which time they had built the Tabernacle and celebrated their first Passover.

Thus, Moses probably used the temporary tent of meeting outside the camp for less than a year.